# Separate symbolic matrix in a sum of matrices sympy

Tags: matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a symbolic matrix where the elements are different functions. this is an example:

```
import sympy as sp

a,b,c,d = sp.symsbols('a, b, c, d')

M = sp.Matrix([[a, b], [c, d]])
```

I would like to rewrite the `M` as sum of matrices without knowing how the matrix are written, like this:

```
M = a*sp.Matrix([1,0],[0,0]) + b*sp.Matrix([0,1],[0,0]) +c*sp.Matrix([0,0],[1,0])+ d*sp.Matrix([,0],[0,1])
```

or a list of the different functions:

```
[a*sp.Matrix([1,0],[0,0]), b*sp.Matrix([0,1],[0,0]) ,c*sp.Matrix([0,0],[1,0]), d*sp.Matrix([,0],[0,1])]
```

My matrix are some thing like this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. all the element of your matrices are multiplications (hence, of type `Mul`).
2. `i` is the imaginary number.

You can do something like this:

```py
M = Matrix([[2 * a * I, 4 * b], [3 * c, a]])
matrices = []
for s in M.free_symbols:
    term = MatMul(s, M.applyfunc(lambda t: t.coeff(s)), evaluate=False)
    matrices.append(term)
    print(term)
# out:
b*Matrix([[0, 4], [0, 0]])
a*Matrix([[2*I, 0], [  0, 1]])
c*Matrix([[0, 0], [3, 0]])
```

First, we loop over the free symbols contained in the matrix. You could also manually insert a list of symbols... With `M.applyfunc` we apply some function to all elements of the matrix. With the aforementioned assumptions, we are retrieving the coefficients of a particular symbol for each element of the matrix. Note the `evaluate=False` inside `MatMul`: if you change it to True, then Sympy evaluates the multiplication, resulting in a single matrix with the symbol inside it.

Eventually, you can add the terms together, for example:

```py
MatAdd(*matrices, evaluate=False)
```