# Substitute functions in sympy matrix

Tags: function, matrix, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a complicated time-dependent Symbolic Matrix, `s` is a normalized time. I wanna separate it as lists of matrices of the same functions. Like this:

```
[[f1,Matrix1],[f2,Matrix2], ... ]
```

This is my matrix:

```
A = Matrix([
[                      0,         16*s*(11*s - 8),          32*s*(5*s - 2), 424*s**2 - 256*s + 64,          32*s*(5*s - 2),       48*s*(7*s - 4), 496*s**2 - 256*s + 64, 648*s**2 - 528*s + 216,         16*s*(11*s - 8),       32*s*(7*s - 4),       48*s*(7*s - 4), 720*s**2 - 624*s + 216, 424*s**2 - 256*s + 64, 720*s**2 - 624*s + 216, 648*s**2 - 528*s + 216,               288*s**2],
[        16*s*(8 - 11*s),                       0,                 72*s**2,        32*s*(5*s - 2),                 48*s**2,              96*s**2,   216*s**2 - 48*s + 8,  368*s**2 - 128*s + 64,                       0,       16*s*(7*s - 4),  224*s**2 - 80*s + 8,        16*s*(13*s - 4),   224*s**2 - 80*s + 8,  296*s**2 - 128*s + 64,               192*s**2, 456*s**2 - 336*s + 216],
[         32*s*(2 - 5*s),                -72*s**2,                       0,        16*s*(7*s - 4),                       0,  168*s**2 - 48*s + 8,               96*s**2,         16*s*(5*s + 4),                -48*s**2,   80*s**2 - 80*s + 8,              48*s**2,                96*s**2,    72*s**2 - 48*s + 8,                96*s**2,  296*s**2 - 128*s + 64, 336*s**2 - 240*s + 216],
[ -424*s**2 + 256*s - 64,          32*s*(2 - 5*s),          16*s*(4 - 7*s),                     0,     -72*s**2 + 48*s - 8,                    0,               48*s**2,           32*s*(s + 2),    -224*s**2 + 80*s - 8,             -48*s**2,                    0,           16*s*(4 - s),                     0,      8*s**2 + 16*s + 8,     96*s**2 + 48*s + 8,          168*s**2 + 64],
[         32*s*(2 - 5*s),                -48*s**2,                       0,    72*s**2 - 48*s + 8,                       0,              48*s**2,               96*s**2,  296*s**2 - 128*s + 64,                -72*s**2,   80*s**2 - 80*s + 8,  168*s**2 - 48*s + 8,                96*s**2,        16*s*(7*s - 4),                96*s**2,         16*s*(5*s + 4), 336*s**2 - 240*s + 216],
[         48*s*(4 - 7*s),                -96*s**2,    -168*s**2 + 48*s - 8,                     0,                -48*s**2,                    0,               72*s**2,                96*s**2,    -224*s**2 + 80*s - 8,             -72*s**2,                    0,    104*s**2 + 16*s + 8,                     0,                48*s**2,     96*s**2 + 48*s + 8,           48*s*(4 - s)],
[ -496*s**2 + 256*s - 64,    -216*s**2 + 48*s - 8,                -96*s**2,              -48*s**2,                -96*s**2,             -72*s**2,                     0,           16*s*(4 - s),    -216*s**2 + 48*s - 8,             -96*s**2,             -72*s**2,    -48*s**2 + 48*s + 8,              -48*s**2,    -48*s**2 + 48*s + 8,           16*s*(4 - s),           32*s*(4 - s)],
[-648*s**2 + 528*s - 216,  -368*s**2 + 128*s - 64,         16*s*(-5*s - 4),         32*s*(-s - 2),  -296*s**2 + 128*s - 64,             -96*s**2,          16*s*(s - 4),                      0,               -192*s**2, -152*s**2 - 16*s - 8,  -96*s**2 - 48*s - 8,               -72*s**2,   -96*s**2 - 48*s - 8,               -48*s**2,                      0,         16*s*(8 - 5*s)],
[        16*s*(8 - 11*s),                       0,                 48*s**2,   224*s**2 - 80*s + 8,                 72*s**2,  224*s**2 - 80*s + 8,   216*s**2 - 48*s + 8,               192*s**2,                       0,       16*s*(7*s - 4),              96*s**2,  296*s**2 - 128*s + 64,        32*s*(5*s - 2),        16*s*(13*s - 4),  368*s**2 - 128*s + 64, 456*s**2 - 336*s + 216],
[         32*s*(4 - 7*s),          16*s*(4 - 7*s),     -80*s**2 + 80*s - 8,               48*s**2,     -80*s**2 + 80*s - 8,              72*s**2,               96*s**2,    152*s**2 + 16*s + 8,          16*s*(4 - 7*s),                    0,              72*s**2,                96*s**2,               48*s**2,                96*s**2,    152*s**2 + 16*s + 8,          240*s**2 + 64],
[         48*s*(4 - 7*s),    -224*s**2 + 80*s - 8,                -48*s**2,                     0,    -168*s**2 + 48*s - 8,                    0,               72*s**2,     96*s**2 + 48*s + 8,                -96*s**2,             -72*s**2,                    0,                48*s**2,                     0,    104*s**2 + 16*s + 8,                96*s**2,           48*s*(4 - s)],
[-720*s**2 + 624*s - 216,         16*s*(4 - 13*s),                -96*s**2,          16*s*(s - 4),                -96*s**2, -104*s**2 - 16*s - 8,    48*s**2 - 48*s - 8,                72*s**2,  -296*s**2 + 128*s - 64,             -96*s**2,             -48*s**2,                      0,    -8*s**2 - 16*s - 8,                      0,                48*s**2,           32*s*(s + 2)],
[ -424*s**2 + 256*s - 64,    -224*s**2 + 80*s - 8,     -72*s**2 + 48*s - 8,                     0,          16*s*(4 - 7*s),                    0,               48*s**2,     96*s**2 + 48*s + 8,          32*s*(2 - 5*s),             -48*s**2,                    0,      8*s**2 + 16*s + 8,                     0,           16*s*(4 - s),           32*s*(s + 2),          168*s**2 + 64],
[-720*s**2 + 624*s - 216,  -296*s**2 + 128*s - 64,                -96*s**2,    -8*s**2 - 16*s - 8,                -96*s**2,             -48*s**2,    48*s**2 - 48*s - 8,                48*s**2,         16*s*(4 - 13*s),             -96*s**2, -104*s**2 - 16*s - 8,                      0,          16*s*(s - 4),                      0,                72*s**2,           32*s*(s + 2)],
[-648*s**2 + 528*s - 216,               -192*s**2,  -296*s**2 + 128*s - 64,   -96*s**2 - 48*s - 8,         16*s*(-5*s - 4),  -96*s**2 - 48*s - 8,          16*s*(s - 4),                      0,  -368*s**2 + 128*s - 64, -152*s**2 - 16*s - 8,             -96*s**2,               -48*s**2,         32*s*(-s - 2),               -72*s**2,                      0,         16*s*(8 - 5*s)],
[              -288*s**2, -456*s**2 + 336*s - 216, -336*s**2 + 240*s - 216,        -168*s**2 - 64, -336*s**2 + 240*s - 216,         48*s*(s - 4),          32*s*(s - 4),         16*s*(5*s - 8), -456*s**2 + 336*s - 216,       -240*s**2 - 64,         48*s*(s - 4),          32*s*(-s - 2),        -168*s**2 - 64,          32*s*(-s - 2),         16*s*(5*s - 8),                      0]])
```

This function put the `A` functions in a Python Set

```
import sympy as sp

def funcs_in_H(M):
    functions = set()
    for element in M:
        functions.add(element)
    return functions


f = funcs_in_H(A)
```

I remove the `0` and create a list of all the functions except for one of then:

```
f.remove(0)
f_minus_1 = []
for _i in f:
    g = f.copy()
    g.remove(_i)
    f_minus_1.append(g)
```

Create a list of dictionaries to use `.subs({})` that will substitute all the function for `0` except for the one I desire to find the component.

```
f_minus_1_dic = []
for _i in f_minus_1:
    f_minus_1_dic.append(
        {_f: 0 for _f in _i}
    )
```

But for some reason it gives me zero matrices for all dictionaries:

```
A.subs(f_minus_1_dic[0])
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want if you are unhappy with the output as shown. You've made a dict that maps everything to zero and then when you use it for substitution it maps everything to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at your code, but reading your first sentence I believe you are trying to achieve a result similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76307223/separate-symbolic-matrix-in-a-sum-of-matrices-sympy). So we are going to use a similar procedure.

If I look at your matrix, I see each element is a polynomial in `s`. Moreover, if `p1` is a polynomial in `s` contained in `M` (your matrix), then it will likely contains `-p1`.

```py
s = symbols("s")
M = Matrix([
    [16*s*(8 - 11*s), 0, 32*s*(5*s - 2)],
    [32*s*(2 - 5*s), 16*s*(11*s - 8), 424*s**2 - 256*s + 64],
    [-424*s**2 + 256*s - 64, 0, -216*s**2 + 48*s - 8]
])

# given an element of the matrix, t, and a polynomial f, check
# if t == f or t == -f
def is_element_equal_to_f(t, f):
    if t.expand() == f.expand():
        return 1
    elif t.expand() == -f.expand():
        return -1
    return 0

# retrieve all the polynomials from the matrix
expand = True
all_funcs = list(set([e for e in M if e != 0]))
# let f be a polynomial. Create a list of polynomials such
# that it contains f but not -f
funcs = []
funcs_expanded = []
for f in all_funcs:
    if (f.expand() not in funcs_expanded) and (-f.expand() not in funcs_expanded):
        funcs.append(f)
        funcs_expanded.append(f.expand())

# build the matrices
matrices = []
for f in zip(funcs, funcs_expanded):
    f = f[1] if expand else f[0]
    term = MatMul(f, M.applyfunc(lambda t: is_element_equal_to_f(t, f)), evaluate=False)
    matrices.append(term)
    print(term)
```

Outputs:

```
(-216*s**2 + 48*s - 8)*Matrix([
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1]])
(160*s**2 - 64*s)*Matrix([
[ 0, 0, 1],
[-1, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 0]])
(-176*s**2 + 128*s)*Matrix([
[1,  0, 0],
[0, -1, 0],
[0,  0, 0]])
(424*s**2 - 256*s + 64)*Matrix([
[ 0, 0, 0],
[ 0, 0, 1],
[-1, 0, 0]])
```

Eventually, add them together:

```py
MatAdd(*matrices, evaluate=False)
```

Try set `expand=False` to see a slightly different output.

Comment: Thanks man, You always answers my questions. I love you s2